# Fade out animation in pure CSS

Tags: css

Coming from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334132/3779853: Let's assume a basic element that gets toggled programmatically. This could mean setting display to none/block or removing/inserting the element altogether.

```js
$('#toggle').click(() => $('#square').toggle());
```

```css
#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.animated {
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<div id="square" class="animated"></div>
```

With a simple `animation`, you can add a transition effect for when the element appears. How do you do the same thing for when the element disappears?

I do not want to add further classes, no `:hover`, and no more Javascript code. In many JS frameworks, you can show/hide elements easily: `.toggle()` (JQuery, as above), `ng-if` (AngularJS), `*ngIf` (Angular), conditional rendering (React), `v-if` (VueJS) and so on. With above solution, a simple `class="animated"` is enough to have it appear with custom animations. So I am looking for a pure CSS solution for fade out animation here, assuming this is a standard problem.

Comment: You can't do this without "more JavaScript code" or "adding further classes". `toggle()` simply applies `display: none;`, and `display` is not an animatable/transitionable property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 100% pure css solution.

```css
#square {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: lightblue;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#myBox:checked ~ .animated {
  opacity: 0;
}
#myBox ~ .animated {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myBox" style="display:none;"/>
<button id="toggle"><label for="myBox">toggle</label></button>
<div id="square" class="animated"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the opacity property with transition effect.

```js
$('#toggle').click(() => $('#square').toggleClass('animated'));
```

```css
#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
#square.animated {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<div id="square" class="animated"></div>
```